# Polar plot coordinates are wrong

Tags: r, plot, polar-coordinates

I want to draw a simple polar plot of cos(ang) in R using polar.plot, but the result is a plot with center in (-1) and the resultant plot don't have any sense. For example is not 0 in 90°. How can I solve this problem?

```
library(plotrix)
grados=seq(0,350,by=10)
radian=grados*pi/180
coseno=cos(radian)  
polar.plot(coseno,grados,rp.type="p")
```

Comment: Hi, its true!, but the center would be in 0 y the resultant plot must be a "8" shape: (for 0°:1, for 90°:0, for 180°:-1, and for 270°:0) I don't really understand why it have cardio form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that I completely understand your problem, but you should have a look at the help for `radial.plot`, which explains a lot of the arguments used in `polar.plot`. In the example below, I add three arguments that may help you set up your plot definitions (`start`,`radial.lim`, and `clockwise`)

```
polar.plot(coseno,grados, rp.type="p", start=90, radial.lim=c(-1,1.5), clockwise=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: ok, I´m sove the problem, with radial.lim=c(0,1), and abs values, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Solution;

```
library(plotrix)
grad=seq(0,359,by=1)
rad=grad*pi/180  # degrees to radian
func=(cos(rad))
func=abs(func)   # negative numbers not plot
polar.plot(func,grad,rp.type="p",radial.lim=c(0,1),
            lwd=2,line.col=4,main="Polar Plot")
```

[image]